# data passed to MatDialogRef component not displayed

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, angular-material

I followed this article: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples 
and made some small changes to pass an class object instead.

I am convinced that the data is passed onto the modal component by looking at the output of this:

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

below is code snippet for better understand the issue:

Under the modal component:

```
@input expense: Expense;

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ExpenseModalComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: Expense
    ) {
      //this.expense= data;
   }
```

Within the parent component:

```
openModalWin(exp: Expense):void
   {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ExpenseModalComponent, {
      height: '400px',
      width: '600px',
      data: {expense: exp} 
    });
```

the model component template:

`{{expense.ExpenseID}}`
blah blah

if I do not comment the two lines of code commented out above, the modal window is blank.

I also tried to use the  to render the result which yield same.

however if I commented out the two lines of code above then ... works just fine.

any idea why the data binding stops working when the component is dispalyed within the modal dialog?

thanks advance for any advices.

Comment: check the console for errors

Answer (score 0):

hmm... look like I missed something , the working one is as below with changes in bold

```
@input expense: Expense;

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ExpenseModalComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: **any**
    ) {
      **this.expense= data.expense;**
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the data, which contain expense key value pair,
Use **this.data** to access the object in matDialogRef